# Chamar a função Javascript do arquivo pai de dentro de um iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

Tenho 2 arquivos:

- `index.html`
- `iframe.html`

O arquivo `index.html` tem um iframe(`iframe.html`).

Existe uma função javascript no arquivo `index.html`

```
function testePai(){
    console.log("teste da função");
}
```

Como faço para chamar esta função `testePai()` a partir de javascript existente no arquivo `iframe.html`?

Answer (score 11):

> **Nota:**
>   Há uma proteção chamada [CORS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/145493/129) que impede abrir conteúdo de um site dentro de iFrame se o servidor não o permitir.
>   Há outra regra chamada "*same-origin policy*" que impede que um script de uma página interaja com outra página se tiverem o mesmo domínio.

Se as regras que referi em cima não o impedirem podes chamar essa função na página `index.html` com código dentro da iFrame assim:

```
window.parent.testePai();
```

Se precisar de fazer o contrário, usando javascript puro:

```
var iframeEl= document.getElementById("myIframe"); // ou outro seletor
var iframeDoc = iframeEl.contentDocument || iframeEl.contentWindow.document;
var iframe= iframeDoc.window;

// para chamar a função
iframe.minhaFuncao();
```

Comment: Boa @sergio, o contrário eu realmente nunca tinha visto funcionar. A um tempo atrás penei com isso, pesquisei mas não tinha achado uma solução que funcionasse bem.

Comment: @ErlonCharles sim, e usando jQuery por exemplo fica só: `$('#myIframe')[0].contentWindow.minhaFuncao()`

Comment: Tá... Tu usou o jQuery praticamente só substituindo o *query selector* do js, depois daí continuou com js puro. Essa seria uma solução mista então, hehe. Ainda sim uma boa.

Answer (score 2):

Para conseguir chamar os métodos, variáveis e objetos da página pai você precisa usar o `window.parent`.

Desta Forma você poderá usar esta como se estivesse na própria página da seguinte forma:

```
window.parent.testePai();
```

Considero uma boa prática definir uma variável para conseguir acessar o *parent* de uma forma mais organizada, exemplo:

```
var index = window.parent; // você pode usar o nome que lhe for mais agradável para esta variável
index.testePai();
```